# How to use string array coming from webservice to INSPhotoViewable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an array of image url `["http://1.jpg", "http://2.jpg", "http://3.jpg", "http://4.jpg"]` coming from webservice. Now I want to show that images with extention INSPhotoGallery [INSPhotoGallery](https://cocoapods.org/?q=INSPhotoGallery)

This is workig fine:

```
    lazy var photos: [INSPhotoViewable] = {

    return [

        INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: "http://1.jpg"), thumbnailImage: UIImage(named: "thumbnailImage")!),

        INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: "http://2.jpg"), thumbnailImage: UIImage(named: "thumbnailImage")!),

        INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: "http://3.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: URL(string: "thumbnailImage")),

        INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: "http://4.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: URL(string: "thumbnailImage")),

        INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: "http://5.jpg"), thumbnailImageURL: URL(string: "thumbnailImage"))

    ]
}()
```

But I am not able to return the images dynamically. What to do if I get 10 or 100 images from web service. How to display that, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map like this

```
let imgUrlArr = ["http://1.jpg", "http://2.jpg", "http://3.jpg", "http://4.jpg"]
var photos: [INSPhotoViewable] = imgUrlArr.map { INSPhoto(imageURL: URL(string: $0), thumbnailImage: UIImage(named: "thumbnailImage")!) }
```